# Understanding the Big O Notation O(2^N)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I am trying to understand how the following recursive function for calculating the Fibonacci series falls under the notation O(2^N).

```
int fibo(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1) return num;
    return fibonacci(num - 2) + fibonacci(num - 1);
}
```

For example, if we consider the finding the Fibonacci series for the number "5", the fibo method is invoked 15 times. How do we say that it falls under the notation O(2^N)?

```
                             fibo(5)
                        --------------------
                        /                  \
                  fibo(3)                   fibo(4)
                ------------              -------------  
                  /       \               /           \
            fibo(2)        fibo(1)   fibo(3)           fib0o(2)
      ----------------             ----------          -------------
       /            \              /        \           /         \
   fibo(1)          fibo(1)  fibo(2)        fibo(1)  fibo(1)      fibo(0)
                            ---------
                            /       \
                       fibo(1)       fibo(0)
```

I know my question is trivial. Please consider me as a novice, trying to learn Big-O notation.

Answer (score 2):

Big Oh provides you a upper bound for the runtime of your algorithm. That is, 
you must read fib(n) in O(2^n) as stating that your algorithm perform at most 2^n steps to return a result. Sometimes, upper bounds are not that precise (this is the case). You also can say that fib is in O(n!), that is another upper bound (a really bad one).

For stating the precise runtime of your algorithm you have to use Theta notation, in this case fib is Theta(Phi^n) where Phi is the golden ratio.You can prove this by induction.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation isn’t meant to calculate the actual number of operations / amount of time / amount of memory. It’s meant to model the overall rate or shape of growth in those quantities as N grows toward infinity. Note that the constant factor has no bearing on Big-O — there is no difference between 3 x O(2^N) and 100 x O(2^N). It’s not at all meant to be a number.

The difference between 15x and 16x is meaningless in a scaled performance situation, while the difference between N^2 and N^2.1 is enormous for large enough N.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the theory here (https://algorithmtutor.com/Analysis-of-Algorithm/Solving-Recurrence-Relations-Part-I/)

[image]